# How to Call R script in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, r

I am trying to create a web application using Angular JS.

And i have created some visuals using R language.

I would like to show these visuals into Angular JS application.

Can anyone please suggest me how can i call those r script files into Angular JS application.

Thanks,

Mohan V

Comment: Perhaps check the [opencpu](http://jsfiddle.net/user/opencpu/fiddles/)